# PL/SQL Query does not return proper value

Tags: sql, plsql

My query is

```
SELECT        COUNT(*)
INTO          L_HAS_CALC
FROM          TABLE1
WHERE         TABLE1_COL1 >= (
SELECT        MAX(TABLE2.TABLE2_COL1)
FROM          TABLE2
               ,TABLE3
WHERE         TABLE2.TABLE2_COL2 = TABLE3.TABLE_3_COL1
    AND         TABLE2.TABLE2_COL3 = TO_DATE('02.03.17','dd.mm.yy')
    AND         TABLE2.TABLE2_COL4 = 32
    AND         TABLE2.TABLE2_COL5 = 65
 )
 AND         TABLE1_COL2 = 65;
```

If ran from a script, it returns 0.
If ran directly in SQL, it returns greater than 0.

I hid the name of tables and columns as it is confidential.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. Please take care when tagging your question

Comment: table structure and sample data would help us identify the difference.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your question. Only plain SQL

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the vague question. Problem has been solved. The issue is about restricted sessions that can only be viewed in certain conditions, which I cannot disclose.

Thanks.